# Open previously opened project in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I am working in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2. I have created a java project, code it, run it, and after work finish i closed the Netbeans. But after sometime, when i restart the netbeans, i see the blank page except menu and toolbar. Every time i select the `File->Open Project` to reopen my previous working project and open their jsp files and java classes and also open `Services`, `Output`, and `Navigator` window. Every time i do this things.

What is the Configuration setting of Netbeans to Open previously opened working project in Netbeans.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do by only one simple step. Go to menu bar and click on `Window` tab and then click `Reset Windows`.

After that the NetBeans window is closed and open again automatically. It open the previous working files, you will not need to open manually.